# BASH file test operators with empty strings

Tags: bash

What do the BASH file test operators return when the path argument is an empty string? For example:

```
directory=""
# Something may or may not set "directory"
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
    # Do something...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote `$directory`:

```
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
```

Otherwise, after expansion you are left with the equivalent of

```
if [ -d ]; then
```

which is equivalent to `if [ -n "-d" ]; then`, and so is always true. (`-d` is a non-empty string.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the statement will yield the following test:

```
if [ -d  ]; then
   ...
fi
```

Which will not test what you wish to.

What is the accepted practice to prevent such error is to encase the variable in double quotes like this:

```
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
   ...
fi
```